# Shortcut to quickly enter .com in browser on Mac OS

Tags: macos, shortcut, web-browser

In Windows, we can use Ctrl+Enter to quickly input .com in browsers. I wonder if there is any equivalent shortcut in Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define shortcuts using the system preferences (Apple menu Top left) and select keyboard as per :
[image: System preferences]

Then add what you want, such as:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94976/discussion-on-answer-by-solar-mike-shortcut-to-quickly-enter-com-in-browser-on).